# Negativar uma pergunta duplicada?

Tags: suporte

Devo ou não negativar uma pergunta duplicada?

No meu caso levo em consideração (algo que aprendi aqui) é apenas **"Auxilia o motor de busca?"**.

Existem mais prós e/ou contras negativar ou não? Ou até "positivar"?

Comment:  é brincadeira bicho!

Comment: Agora falta o pessoal negativar kkkk

Comment: Mas já negativaram antes até! hahahaha

Comment: Rbz, gosto de ajudar em suas perguntas, mas acho que pergunta dup pode até ajudar, mas não deveria levar "o down" para o 8 ou 80, tem critica em -1 que apenas quer dizer: *"isso já tem muitas perguntas e respostas, pesquisa um pouco, dê valor as postagens já feitas"*, eu tentei lhe dar um norte lá https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322326/qual-a-vantagem-do-pdo-por-que-us%c3%a1-lo#comment653084_322326, a pergunta **é ampla**, PDO vc usa quando precisa e também usa se vc gosta da maneira que ele foi projetado, é diferente de mysqli. Não sei quem negativou, mas penso q seja este o motivo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Opa fico lisonjeado por gostar das minhas perguntas! E vc já sabe que sempre gosto de ter sua resposta!  Eu nem levei muito no "estresse" o -1, mas é que na minha opinião, se você dá o -1, no mínimo explique o motivo, claro, se esse não estiver muito claro. É tão importante explicar o porque do -1, para nós "aprendermos" como usar o SOpt. Eu só aprendi usar, tomando de exemplo boas perguntas, bons usuários e deletando pergunta e resposta ruins ! rs Eu sou iniciante, não trabalho na área, em uma ferramenta grande como o SO!? Só aprende com tempo mesmo!.. Mas tranquilo ✌️

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que entendo (e levo como critério para negativação) uma pergunta deve receber um *down vote* se ela é não tem muito sentido na elaboração.

Por exemplo [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322331/menu-n%C3%8Dvel-2-vertical-dividido-em-2-ou-mais-colunas); não é fácil entender **o que/como** o *perguntador* pretende resolver o problema (que problema?).

Particularmente uma pergunta duplicada não deve receber *-1* mesmo que não traga algo novo para o leitor; em contra partida, deve receber *+1* caso traga algo novo.

Comment: Já aproveitei e dei fechar nessa pergunta que usou como exemplo! rs

Comment: Sigo esta linha também. Raramente dou algum downvote, só se a pergunta/resposta for muito ruim. É comum perguntas duplicadas serem de usuários que acabaram de chegar ao site e, negativando muito eles, podem acabar por desmotivá-los a continuarem no SOpt.